# Autocomplete the equal and quotes when adding class or ID

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Sublime Text 2 allows me to autocomplete the class or id attribute, but it is not adding the `=""` automatically when I start typing `class=" "`.

I want to type in `<div c` and at the moment the `c` is typed the autocomplete should show the option `class=""` not just `class` but also the equal and the quotes.  The same goes for `id=""` and `style=""`.

I am sure this is fairly simple to do; just installed the software today.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install the Sublime package manager [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) to allow for the easy installation, removal, upgrading, and otherwise managing third-party plugins and packages. Next, after restarting Sublime, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (Windows/Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> (OS X) to bring up the Command Palette. Type `pci` to get to `Package Control: Install`. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then start typing in `HTMLAttributes` until it shows up. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again to install it. You'll now have a much greater selection of auto-completions, including the `class`, `id`, and `style` elements you were looking for. So, inside a tag start typing `class` and when the autocomplete appears, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. The rest of the word `class` will complete, along with an equals sign and a pair of double quotes. Your cursor will automatically be positioned inside the quotes, and when you're done entering the value(s) you want just hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again and your cursor will jump outside the quotes, ready to close the tag or enter the next attribute.

To see what sort of completions are available to you, check out the source [here](https://raw.github.com/agibsonsw/HTMLAttributes/master/HTMLAttributes.sublime-completions) or go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` to open up your system's file explorer, then enter the `HTMLAttributes` directory and open the `HTMLAttributes.sublime-completions` as a JSON file in Sublime. If a `trigger` contains a `\t` (tabstop) character, the part before it is the completion, and the part after it is what appears in the autocomplete menu on the right. In `contents`, `$1`, `$2`, and so on are successive places where hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> will land your cursor. `$0` is the exit point. Something like `${1:form_id}` gives a default value, and something like `"draggable=\"$1${1/(t$)|(f$)|(a$)|.*/?1:rue:?2:alse:?3:uto/i}\"$0"` is an autocomplete regex, so that if you type `t` inside the field, it autocompletes to `true`, if you backspace and hit `f` it becomes `false`, and `a` becomes `auto`.

This package is really great at supplementing the standard HTML autocomplete that ships with Sublime, but unfortunately it doesn't necessarily play nicely with [Emmet](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Emmet), formerly known as Zen Coding, as some of the completions may clash with Emmet's abbreviations. Of course, as always, YMMV.

Good luck!

Comment: Just installed it as explained and didn't work.  Next assumption was that other package was interfering with HTMLAttributes.  Removed CodeIntel and sure enough, now it works.  Brilliant... Thanks.

Comment: @user2339776 Did you restart between installing HTMLAttributes and trying to use it? I have no issues at all with SublimeCodeIntel, and I would highly highly recommend it (slightly tweaked) if you're going to be working with JS, PHP, Python, Ruby, etc. It has made my life so much easier :)